# Why has my question been closed?

Tags: support

I ask to intelligibly and fully explain why [my question](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/15056/8249) has been closed. If it is possible, I’d like to see a reference to the help center, not just a text with claims.

Answer (score 3):

To make a translation-relation question on-topic, following criteria should be met:

1. You need to provide what exactly does the phrase you are looking for translation for mean. **Don't assume that everyone speaks English perfectly well** and understands every English idiom possible. Also, even native speakers can de-facto use the same very idiom quite differently.
2. You need to provide **an evidence of prior research**, whatever it would be, even google translate counts. Ideally you'll have not one but two-three possible translations.
3. You need **clearly indicate why you still believe one can give a better answer** that you already have. Obviously, explanations like "but what if there's better translation" does not count, because you can add this kind of explanation to literally any question asked.

Here's an example of on-topic question:

> Here in Guranji we have a saying "djabaka dee du da djabaka" - *(#1 explanation)* roughly it's about that if you want to achieve something you must work hard. *(#2 - prior research)* I'm thinking of "без труда не вытянешь и рыбки из пруда" - it looks relevant. (#3 - explanation) It's just that original Guranji saying has put more stress on the fact that one should work a lot while in "не вытянешь и рыбки..." just acknowledges the fact that some work is always needed. So may be there's some better match.

Here's an example of off-topic question:

> How can I translate well known Guranji saying:  "djabaka dee du da djabaka"? "Без труда не вытянешь и рыбки из труда?" - but I have some doubts, may be something better? Thanks.

bonus answer to the question not asked yet but I'm almost sure it will be asked: **Q:** but I see question N - and it does not meet criteria listed above and still not closed! It's not fair!!! **A:** Just flag it and moderators will take a look. This is a community-driven place.

Comment: Oh, sorry: it seems like I should write in English at Meta. So, 1) I've adduced some glosses. Is it ok? 2) Is there an evidence of prior research, if 1 is okay and I've got my translation in the question? 3) I wrote: I suppose that there can be some translations which are not 
fixed in dictionaries (and this supposition was approved by Quassnoi♦). I asked you to explain what I haven't got in my question. What should I do to reopen it?